# How to run odoo automated schedule (cron job) on another environment

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have some scheduled actions to generate reports which required millions even billions of raw data, whenever the scheduled action running on back-end, the performance on server is impacted and when users accessing system become slower. The idea now is to execute all scheduled actions on another environment so that it won't consume the production environment resources.

So i'm going to have 3 environments :

1. Database Environment
2. Production Environment
3. Other Environment

"Other Environment" is replicated from production environment in order to run all scheduled actions. Both environment will connect to database environment.

My question is how to configure ir.cron so that on production environment won't run the scheduler, but it will run on other environment instead ?

OR

Any suggestion for another method to achieve my goal which to do heavy process on another environment ??

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question :

I'm using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) & [Odoo web service API](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html) to achieve my goal.

First i create a report class base for all either transient models to capture at the print action method and model, before execution i use thread to throw the action to another environment which i called as QMS (Queue Management System) environment to process its action method.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xmlrpclib
import logging
from functools import partial

from odoo import _, api, fields, models, registry, SUPERUSER_ID

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class BaseReport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'base.report'
    _description = 'Base Object for All Reports'

    @api.multi
    def action_print(self):
        qms_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.qms.url')

        import threading
        # call the maintainence_function here
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.execute_queue, args=[qms_url])
        # setDaemon=False to stop the thread after complete
        t.setDaemon(False)
        # starting the thread
        t.start()

        return True

    @api.multi
    def execute_queue(self, qms_url):
        try:
            _logger.info("Queue [{}] Execution Starting !".format(self.id))

            self.ensure_one()

            common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(qms_url))
            models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(qms_url))
            uid = common.authenticate(self.env.cr.dbname, '{your_username}', '{your_userpassword}', {})

            models.execute_kw(self.env.cr.dbname, uid, '{your_userpassword}', 'queue.management.line', 'execute_thread', [self.id])

            _logger.info("Queue [{}] Execution Done Successfully !".format(self.id))

        except Exception as Ex:
            _logger.exception("Queue [{}] Execution Failed !".format(self.id))

        finally:
            return True

    @api.model
    def execute_thread(self, queue_id):
        def run_queue(queue_id, dbname):
            db_registry = registry(dbname)

            with api.Environment.manage(), db_registry.cursor() as cr:
                env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})

                try:
                    {do_your_action_here}

                except Exception as Ex:
                    _logger.exception("Queue [{}] Execution Failed !".format(queue_id))

        self.env.cr.after("commit", partial(run_queue, queue_id, self.env.cr.dbname))

        return True
```

Hope it helps u as well.